# How to add a checkbox column to a Kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to add a check box column to KendoUI grid.
Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JNMvn/17/).

I have followed [this](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/grid/grid-checkbox.aspx) post from the Kendo forum.
Can somebody please point out what I have done wrong here.

This is the relevant code:

```
data-columns = '[
    {"field":"Name", "filterable":true},
    {"field":"Price", "filterable":false},
    "UnitsInStock",
    {"field":"Recon"},
    "template": "<input type='checkbox' #= (Recon == true) ? checked ='checked' : '' # disabled />"
]'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change your columns to this:

```
[{"field":"Name", "filterable":true}, {"field":"Price", "filterable":false}, "UnitsInStock", {"field":"Recon", "template": "<input type=\"checkbox\" />" }]'
```

You had some errors in your syntax there, as well as some unescaped quotes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It helped indeed. Thank you very much. Now it shows the check box field. But all check boxes are unchecked by default. Is there any way to change the checked status of the check box according to the value in the view model.

Comment: add this the input element:  '# if(Recon){ # checked #}  #'  , That should do it!

Comment: Can I know to which attribute I should assign this value in the input element.

Comment: "Checked" is the attribute, and does not need a value. Your input element in the template should look something like this: '<input type=\"checkbox\" # if(Recon){ # checked #} # />'

Comment: Figured it out myself... {"field":"Recon", "template": "<input type=\"checkbox\" # if(Recon){ # checked #} # />"} I initially thought those two single quotation marks as a part of the answer. Thanks @Logard you saved my day

Answer (score 0):

> In template section use CheckBox see example below:

```
 {
    title: "Deck Options",
    field: "DeckOption",
    template: "<input type='checkbox' #= (DeckOption == true) ? checked ='checked' : '' # disabled/>",
    width: "7%",
    sortable: {
    mode: "single",
    allowUnsort: false
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add an explanation how this solves OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a column as a checkbox column.

```
data-columns = '[
{"field":"Name", "filterable":true},
{"field":"Price", "filterable":false},
"UnitsInStock",
{"field":"Recon"},
{ selectable: true, width: "50px" } //selectable means it's a checkbox column
]'
```