# Is it possible to add custom asp.net controls in Kendo Grid?

Tags: asp.net, kendo-grid

I have stuck with one problem.

I have asp.net application which uses Kendo UI for the presentation of data.

My client needs me to create one report which uses Kendo UI Grid for display data and it will also require some user input by using ASP.net controls like DropDownlist ,Datetime control , Checkbox and Div SHow hide.

Now, my question is, is it possible to add custom controls in the Kendo Grid?

Please reply I am really stuck with this

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/grid/adding-dropdown-list-to-a-grid-column.aspx) to find out more about dropdownlists in Kendo UI grids. Read [this](http://onabai.wordpress.com/2012/10/01/kendoui-time-and-datetime-in-grid-yes-we-can/) to find out more about date pickers. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210105/kendoui-grid-adding-checkbox-column) to find out more about checkboxes. So you can solve all of these, but you will get quicker responses in the future if you do not post composite questions, you have posted several problems in the same question. People do not answer it because they do not bother to solve all your problems in a single question.

Also, you might like to know that defining the column types of the grid's data model (not remember how, as my Kendo UI days are gone and I do not read my old code unless it is absolutely necessary) is a source of miracles.

I hope my post was helpful to you.